# sqlite3: avoiding "database locked" collision

Tags: python, database, sqlite, gunicorn

I am running two python files on one cpu in parallel, both of which make use of the same sqlite3 database. I am handling the sqlite3 database using sqlalchemy and my understanding is that sqlalchemy handles all the threading database issues within one app. My question is how to handle the access from the two different apps? 
One of my two programs is a flask application and the other is a cronjob which updates the database from time to time. 
It seems that even read-only tasks on the sqlite database lock the database, meaning that if both apps want to read or write at the same time I get an error.

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked
```

Lets assume that my cronjob app runs every 5min. How can I make sure that there are no collisions between my two apps? I could write some read flag into a file which I check before accessing the database, but it seems to me there should be a standard way to do this?
Furthermore I am running my app with gunicorn and in principle it is possible to have multiple jobs running... so I eventually want more than 2 parallel jobs for my flask app...
thanks
carl

Comment: You could use a lockfile but your problems would increase with the number oft threads accessing the database. I advise to use a database server (MySQL, PostgresQL...) instead of SQlite.

Comment: Yes SQLite isn't really designed for this use case. @KlausD. is correct you need to replace it.

Comment: I use Flask+sqlite and a task queue that also talks to the db without problems. SQLite can be used from multiple threads/processes.

Comment: hi coleifer... could you explain a bit about your task queue system?

Comment: It's all pretty simple. The tasks are executed by a continuously running python program that listens for events. Whenever a task is run, it connects to the db, then closes the connection on return/error. The web app opens a connection for requests, then closes it at response time.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers - the solution is twofold.

1. You need to manage the exception manually, wait and try again - something like this:

```py
# retry
record = None
for i in range(3):
    try:
        my.sqlite.function()
        break # break out of the retry loop on success
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        time.sleep(0.01)
if not record:
    raise BigError("Bad!")
```

2: You need to enable WAL or Write Ahead Logging mode. This will enable you to read what is already in the database while writing.

Answer (score 0):

It's true.  Sqlite isn't built for this kind of application.  Sqlite is really for lightweight single-threaded, single-instance applications.

Sqlite connections are one per instance, and if you start getting into some kind of threaded multiplexer (see https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) it'd be possible, but it's more trouble than it's worth. And there are other solutions that provide that function-- take a look at Postgresql or MySQL.  Those DB's are open source, are well documented, well supported, and support the kind of concurrency you need.

Comment: This is so not true. http://charlesleifer.com/blog/sqlite-small-fast-reliable-choose-any-three-/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how SQLAlchemy handles connections, but if you were using Peewee ORM then the solution is quite simple.

When your Flask app initiates a request, you will open a connection to the DB. Then when Flask sends the response, you close the DB.

Similarly, in your cron script, open a connection when you start to use the DB, then close it when the process is finished.

Another thing you might consider is using SQLite in WAL mode. This can improve concurrency. You set the journaling mode with a PRAGMA query when you open your connection.

For more info, see http://charlesleifer.com/blog/sqlite-small-fast-reliable-choose-any-three-/